# How to find a value among all columns in a row in HBase

Tags: java, filter, hbase

I have a table in HBase to store user objects. Each object has 4 columns and I name each column as `[object_creation_date]_[column_name]` to auto order columns by object creation date.

```
For example:
RowKey  20140101_a 20140101_b 20140101_c 20140101_d 20140102_a 20140102_b 20140102_c 20140102_d
1        1a          1b         1c          1d         2a          2b        2c        2d
```

Now I'm trying to filter these values by column. Is there any way to find the object (set of 4 columns) whose property `"C"` equals `"2c"`? It should return `20140102`

I tried using `ColumnRangeFilter` class but it only seems to work with prefixes and I´d need a RegExp to find all `"C"` columns no matter the date they were created.

Is there another way of doing this or maybe I could use a different representation for the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always implement your own filter, but why don't you just invert the order of the columns to `[column_name]_[object_creation_date]`? That way you can use the standard ColumnPrefixFilter which seems more appropiate.

---

Anyway, I think you should consider moving from a wide to a tall approach:

```
RowKey      u   a   b   c   d
1_20140101  1   1a  1b  1c  1d
1_20140102  1   2a  2b  2c  2d
1_20140103  1   3a  3b  3c  3d
```

This will allow you to perform very fast scans for a known user or even a full table scan for a known column.

Or, if you want to avoid having multiple rows for the same user you can use [versioning](http://hbase.apache.org/book/versions.html).

---

Tip: For even better query performance you could even build your own "secondary-index" table with this type of row keys: `[column]_[4char_md5_of_value]_[user_id]`

```
RowKey    value   u  d 
a_afaa_1  1a      1  20140101 
a_a32a_1  2a      1  20140102
a_45ae_1  3a      1  20140103
b_l413_1  1b      1  20140101 
b_533a_1  2b      1  20140102
b_8ce3_1  3b      1  20140103
c_b31c_1  1c      1  20140101 
c_2ca1_1  2c      1  20140102
c_a99f_1  3c      1  20140103
```

This would make looking for any column value ultra fast: For the value you want to search, perform the md5, and get the first 4 chars of the hex string, with that do a scan providing the row prefix `[column]_[hash]`, and add the ColumnValue filter (because there could be multiple values under the same hash).

You can also restrict this table to the column/s you'll be querying to avoid saving data you won't need.

Comment: Ok that's exactly what I expected and the only problem with your approach is, if I invert the order, I cannot take advantage of the auto order. And it's important for me because I use it in a paged list and I don't want to order it myself to show the last N objects (by user). 

On the other hand, I avoided spliting them in rows because I think this kind of databases are intended to be used in a "column way" rather than "row way" as traditional relational databases

Comment: That's not true, tables are not meant to be wide per-se, sure, they can be a little more I/O efficient but they're a lot more complex to handle (as you're experiencing now) and in the end, it all depends on your data access pattern (more info here: http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#schema.smackdown). Anyway, building a secondary index for column searches will be the fastest method by far, enough for handling tons of realtime queries (only works with exact matches).

Answer (score 0):

Since the structure of your qualifiers is fixed to 9 bytes of date + seperator it would be relatively easy to  create your own filter by modifying the code of the [ColumnPrefixFilter](http://search-hadoop.com/c/HBase%3ahbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ColumnPrefixFilter.java%7C%7Cprefix+salt+key+hotspot)

Each line where it compares bytes of the qualifier name just add 9 to the offset as in

`int cmp = Bytes.compareTo(buffer,` **`qualifierOffset + 9`**`, qualifierLength, this.prefix, 0, qualifierLength);`